# python selenium send_keys error: list object has no attribute

Tags: python, selenium

```
mail = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
```

```
username = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')
username.sendkey(mail)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sendkey'

i just want to fill email elements with sendkey

Comment: Are there more than one element with `id=email`? That is very strange honestly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value= '//*[@id="email"]').send_keys(mail)
```